# How do people validate their websites in 2013?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, validation

There are several options for validating websites available:

- Paste each URL into an online validator (http://validator.w3.org)
- Run a module on your web server ([mod_tidy](http://mod-tidy.sourceforge.net/), "Although mod_tidy makes the impression of being a validator, it isn't one")
- Install a browser extension ([Chrome HTML Validator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo?hl=en))
- Paste HTML source into a validator (http://validator.w3.org)
- Run a proxy ([Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/))

But none of them has the ultimate feature set:

- Intercept all requests, even subsequent to page load (HTML, CSS, JS, AJAX, JSON, XML)
- Do all processing locally without loading validator.w3c.org or similar
- Process automatically without requiring to "submit" each resource for validation
- Be actively developed (works with HTML5)

Are real people out there using any good tools to make this easier, or is validation moot until IE is eradicated?

Comment: Ah good old times with validation... :)

Comment: Remember the 90's... DHTML, no CSS, lovely XHTML error messages?

Comment: Offtopic: http://divshot.github.io/geo-bootstrap/ LOL

Comment: Oh, now with Google forking WebKit to form Blink, I think IE is the least of your worries.

Comment: hahahaahha@Miljan...kinda looks like my very first website. LOL

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I like the "Input with error" styling :)

Answer (score 3):

In general, I just use a small conditional statement for IE, and have no stylesheet for older versions of internet explorer(if they are still stuck in the stone age of ie5-7, they don't need the new technologies of CSS). Apart from that, I use w3c validator and jstidy. Maybe I am just out of date, but in general, HTML is a very flexible language, and it is really not that big of a deal if it is 'XHTML or HTML compliant, as long as it works as you want it to.

Comment: I agree....as long as works in all major browsers the way it should be...even Search Engines are smart enough to pick up HTML pretty fast even if it has minor issues.